Automatically group rows with same "level" indicator in "nested" data structure
Is there a VBA way to automatically group rows in excel of data having same "level indicator" in nested data structure like this:
The Structure

Excel VBA is more like unknown waters for me: I'm scripting in VBA for CATIA software only so far, but atm I need to deal with big chunk of data in MS Excel ;)
Thanks in advance

I am not able to understand what you try doing... Do you mean Excel groups (Data - Outline - Group), or something else? It would be good to do it manually for  the data you show above and place another picture with desired output/result...

The quick answer is "yes," it is possible, though to the level of difficulty...  What have you tried thusfar?  SO is not a code-for-you service; aiding in specific issues is the name of the game, such as an error with your existing code.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
